# Merge network[-]manager tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There are two tags for NetworkManager: [networkmanager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networkmanager) and [network-manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-manager)  The former is more popular but I personally like the latter.  Either way these should be merged.

Answer (score 3):

The tool is called "NetworkManager" (as opposed to "Network Manager"), so I kept [networkmanager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networkmanager). There was only one [network-manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-manager) post, but I made a synonym anyway in case it happens again

Comment: There's no way to create [tag:network-manager] when [tag:networkmanager] except if the editor is a ♦moderator. But it's good to keep the hyphenated version for migrations from [ubuntu.se] because there the tag is [hyphenated](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/network-manager).